# How to return a 500 status code if there is an IOException while reading

Tags: java, exception

Say I have the following snippet

```
public boolean checkListing() {

    try {

        // open the users.txt file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            // only interested for duplicate usernames
            if (username.equals(values[0])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // what to do here
    }

}
```

How should I handle the error if an exception occurs?
I want to know that it happened and return a 500 code back to the user.

Should I throw and exception and catch it in the other class?

Is there a more elegant way to get feedback on it?

Comment: 1) throw exception holding initial exception as a cause; 2) use composite `{result, code, failure reason}` object to return. I prefer 1) because it is both elegant and useful: from any point of execution you can get full trace of failure.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks for your answer. I have a bit of trouble understanding though. Can you give me a source to read more about the 2nd way?

Comment: BTW don't forget to close `br` in `finally` block, otherwise sequence of failures can cause resource leak.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I'm sorry, but as i said, i did not understand your suggestions. Apologies if i can't quite follow.

Comment: I mean that all resources as `FileReader`s and `BufferedReader`s should be closed at the end of execution. In my answer I provided code snippet how to manage it automatically.

Comment: Without knowing the context of this code, it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an instance of this class:

```
public class Result {

    private boolean errorOccurs;
    private boolean isValid;
    private Exception exception;

    public Result(boolean isValid){
        this(isValid, false, null);
    }

    public Result(boolean isValid, boolean errorOccurs, Exception exception){
        this.isValid = isValid;
        this.errorOccurs = errorOccurs;
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public boolean isValid(){
        return isValid;
    }

    public boolean errorOccurs(){
        return errorOccurs;
    }

    public Exception getException(){
        return exception;
    }
}
```

In your case:

```
public Result checkListing() {

    try {

        // open the users.txt file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            // only interested for duplicate usernames
            if (username.equals(values[0])) {
                return new Result(true);
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return new Result(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Result(false, true, e);
    }
}
```

And the short form of the Result class:)

```
public class Result {
    public boolean errorOccurs;
    public boolean isValid;
    public Exception exception;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for the on point answer sir.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `IOException` can be thrown from `readLine` or `close`.

This exception indicates that exceptional situation happened, for example the stream's source is no longer available. Your program *can* be recovered, or by rereading the source or reporting this problem to the user.

It's up to you to decide what to do, depending on your logic, there's no preferred way of doing that here.

Note that you should close `br` in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to throw wrapping exception:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("users.txt")) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {

        // ... do your work

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e1); 
}
```

Notice, that here I'm opening resources in `try` statements thus making them to be closed automatically at the end of execution, not dependent on execution result.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common approaches I have seen are, as noted by Sasha Salauyou, a rethrow (potentially wrapped) or a separate object providing more information.

The fundamental problem that you're trying to deal with here is that you have a method that you want to have returning more than two values with a return type that can only express two. So you either have to return a type that supports all the possible return values you need or you have to find alternate return paths (like exceptions).

In my own code, I would tend to favor a rethrow here. Writing a dedicated return object becomes difficult to maintain long term with IO because there are so many diverse ways that things can fail. However, I would diverge from the route suggested (an exception holding the original exception as cause) simply because there is usually no strong reason for the wrapping. Just declare your checkListing method to throw IOException, log your message or stacktrace in the catch block, and then throw the original exception.